# Mac did a weird random shutdown

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, crash

Other people have asked about this but I did not see anything quite like what happened to me since the fixes seems to apply to later models.

I use a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) - 8 GB RAM. The model ID is MacBookPro9,2 Running Catalina 10.15.6

Anyhow, I am using my mac one morning and the screen goes black as though it were going to sleep, but it did not respond to my keyboard taps and clicking the trackpad. I tried a restart via power button and it didn't seem to work, I then unplugged it from the power cord and tried again and it restarted -- no error message on restart, saying it had restarted because of a problem. It just went to the login screen and restarted as though nothing had happened -- my apps and windows were all open as before.

This has happened a few times and it worries me a bit. But the intervals are random, I don't recall a similar system for some months.

I tried to attach the system log but it seems to be too long (it went above the 30,000 character limit). Other people who have noted this seem to be saying it's an artifact of Catalina. Any ideas?

Comment: Could either be kernel panic or overheating.

Comment: Hm. is there a good way to diagnose the latter?

Comment: I use Intel power gadget. As long as the laptop is below 100 C, it's fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer but since I am experiencing the same issue on a 2019 iMac: Could you perhaps test whether you can still SSH into the machine in that state? My machine is perfectly accessible through SSH although the screen remains black.